# Want to fix this menu bar to the top

Tags: html, css, menubar

I want to fix this menu bar at the top of the page,so that when user scrolls down, the menu bar continues to appear and the content flows into it.I have tried acheive that by changing position from relative to absolute, but that doesn't worked.

Here is the Css

```
ul.dark_menu {
list-style: none;
padding: 5px 1px;
font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', 'Open Sans', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 200;
font-size: 16px;
letter-spacing: 0.01em;
font-smooth: always;
color: #000000;
line-height: 15px;
margin: auto;
width: 1068px;
position: relative;
background: #2B5797;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu:after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
visibility: hidden;
width: 0;
height: 0;}
ul.dark_menu li {
float: left;
position: relative;
margin: 1px;}
/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu li a, ul.dark_menu li a:link {
color: #fafafa;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 8px 26px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu li a:hover {
color: #fafafa;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu li a.selected {
border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-left: 10px;
}
ul.dark_menu li a.selected, ul.dark_menu li a:active {
color: #fafafa;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;}
ul.dark_menu li ul {
display: none;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu li ul:before {
content: " ";
position: absolute;
display: block;
z-index: 1500;
left: 0;
top: -10px;
height: 10px;
width: 100%;}
ul.dark_menu li ul {-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;top:55px;}
ul.dark_menu li:hover ul {
position: absolute;
display: block;
z-index: 1000;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
left: 0;border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
top: 37px;
padding: 5px 0;
list-style: none;
background: #fff;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu li ul li {
float: none;
margin:0px;}
ul.dark_menu li ul li:first-child {
margin:0px;
border-top: 0 none;}
ul.dark_menu li ul li:last-child {
border-bottom: 0 none;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu [data-role="dropdown"] > a::before {
position: absolute;
content: "^";
display: block;
font-size: 15px;
left: 100%;
margin-left: -20px;
top: 10px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
ul.dark_menu li ul li a, ul.dark_menu li ul li a:link {
color: #222;
display: block;
background: transparent none;
padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
white-space: nowrap;}
ul.dark_menu li ul li a:hover {
background:#2D89EF;-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;color:#fff;
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
.menujohanes{position:relative;}
#search input[type="text"]:hover {width:848px;}
#search input[type="text"] {
background: #fff url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-uYZni0pIn-E/T-xY2vVu_-I/AAAAAAAACUY/ZMfR3_BvRFE/s1600/SEARCH_32x32-32.png")no-repeat center left;
font-size: 13px;
color: #222;
width: 0px;
padding: 10px 0px 11px 35px;
z-index: 9;
border: 1px solid #fff;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
margin-bottom: -1px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right:27px;}

ul.dark_menu li ul li ul li { display: none; }
ul.dark_menu li ul li:hover ul li { display: block;}
ul.dark_menu li ul li:hover ul { left: 100%; top: 0; }
```

and the html

```
<div class='menujohanes'>
        <ul class='dark_menu'>
          <li>
            <a class='selected' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' title='Home'>
              Home
            </a>
          </li>

       <li data-role='dropdown'>
            <a href='#'>
              Categories
            </a>
            <ul>
                 <li>
                    <a href='#'>
                   Funny Pictures
                    </a>
                        <ul>
                       <li><a href='#'>Funny Gifs</a></li>    

                          <li><a href='#'>Funny Pictures :)</a></li>    
                   </ul>
                </li>
<li>
                <a href='#'>
                  Entertainment
                </a>
<ul>
                       <li><a href='#'>Celebrities Pictures</a></li>    
                </ul> 
              </li>
               <li>
                <a href='#'>
                 Sports
                </a>
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href='#'>Soccer Photos</a></li>    

                       <li><a href='#'>Cricket Stars</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Famous Tennis Players Pictures</a></li>    
<li><a href='#'>WWE Superstars</a></li>    

                   </ul>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form action='/search' id='search' method='get'>
          <input name='q' placeholder='Search Somethings..' size='40' type='text'/>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the div that you want to stay fixed to:

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
```

The z-index is there to make sure the content flows under it. This value can be any positive number as long as its greater than any other element that you want to flow under it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

in your case make `ul.dark_menu` `position:fixed;`